# ngx-flip no funciona

Tags: angular, aplicación-web

Descripcion:
estoy desarrolando una pagina web y al copilar mi pagina en angular me saltaron los siguientes errores y no se por que me han aperecido si antes funcionaba bien

Error:

```
src/app/pointofsale/pointofsale.component.ts:6:16
        6   templateUrl: './pointofsale.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component PointofsaleComponent.
    src/app/pointofsale/pointofsale.component.html:69:19 - error NG8001: 'ngx-flip' is not a known element:
    1. If 'ngx-flip' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'ngx-flip' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    
    69                   <ngx-flip [flip]="flip2">
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/pointofsale/pointofsale.component.ts:6:16
        6   templateUrl: './pointofsale.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component PointofsaleComponent.
    src/app/pointofsale/pointofsale.component.html:69:29 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'flip' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-flip'.
    1. If 'ngx-flip' is an Angular component and it has 'flip' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'ngx-flip' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
    
    69                   <ngx-flip [flip]="flip2">
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Parece que no has instalado bien el paquete en tu aplicación (`npm install ngx-flip --save`) o quizás no lo hayas importado en el módulo que toque.

Comment: Deja lo checo vale

Comment: Me temo que no es ninguna de las dos cosas que me dijiste